# SQL - Include multiple substrings?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query in oracle that produces a count, by the UUID field, with a substring of 1,42..this was because we append extra characters after the UUID to represent multiple actions from the same UUID. This query works fine, the problem is, the UUID field also has android Device IDs which are 17 characters long, not the 42 characters that a UUID has. How could I include these "UUIDs" that arent the standard 42 characters?

```
select substr(uuid,1,42), count(player_id)
From Play
Where Trunc(Create_Dtime) >= To_Date('2012-mar-01','yyyy-mon-dd')
Group By Substr(Uuid,1,42)
Having Count(*) > 5
Order By Count(Player_Id) Desc
```

Comment: This sounds like a flaw in your data-model. You shouldn't be "appending" characters to a unique id. Keep the "actions" and the id separate and your query is easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can somehow differentiate Android rows from other ones

```
select
    case when <android-condition> then Substr(Uuid,1,17)
         else Substr(uuid,1,42)
    end
  , count(player_id)
From Play
Where Trunc(Create_Dtime) >= To_Date('2012-mar-01','yyyy-mon-dd')
Group By
    case when <android-condition> then Substr(Uuid,1,17)
         else Substr(uuid,1,42)
    end
Having Count(*) > 5
Order By Count(Player_Id) Desc
```